# Thymeleaf spring loop n item

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am quite new to spring framework.

I try to iterate 10 item in a list. I use thymeleaf template.

This is my code for ;

```
<li th:each="item,iter : ${list}">
        <span th:if="${iter.index} <=10  " th:text="${item}"/>
</li>
```

This code is not working and I could not find a way to run the code.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Is it not working, or could you not run it?  Can you provide more code, and some code that calls it?

Comment: Not working *how*? Wrong output? Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate 10 items in a list. You should:

```
 <li th:each="item, index : ${yourList}" th:unless="${index.index > 10}"></li>
```

This code works. Send me a comment if it doesn't fit for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I would like to ask you how to write the last 10 items?

Comment: To include the last 10 elements:
<li th:each="item, index : ${yourList}" th:if="${index.index >= index.size-10}">

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I would like to my last question. Do you recommend me good online courses to learn more spring, tyhmeleaf?

Comment: I recommend this documentation: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html and stackoverflow.com to learn. You are welcome. You forgot accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This `<span th:if="${iter.index} <=10  " th:text="${item}"/>` not the correct Thymeleaf syntax. The complete expression has to be within the `${}` like `${iter.index <= 10 }`